# Unifont & UnicodeData.txt how do I deduce if character is full or half width (x-advance)

Tags: unicode, fonts, raster, measure

Is there reliable way for determining if glyph in unifont is **half width** like latin characters (ie all in chart 0002) which take left half space only or **full width** like character 0x06E9 (from chart 0006)?

Pixel analysis is not good solution for me as it would fail on many characters like spaces.

I'd prefer to use information from UnicodeData.txt:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Unfortunately I'm not able to find good match between unifont and any field from data.

Chart 0002: http://unifoundry.com/png/plane00/uni0002.png
[image]

Chart 0006: http://unifoundry.com/png/plane00/uni0006.png
[image]

Comment: what are you using? If you have access to the font itself, and can slap a parser on top of it, you can simply check the glyph's width in relation to the font's stated quad size.

Comment: I realize that it would be possible to do some script in ie. fontforge to dump every char x-advance. Unfortunately after installing cygwin, x-win and fontforge it throws exception at startup.

Comment: And back to your question, I want to use Just 1bit bitmap + some width data on SD card attached to Pic uC.

Comment: forntforge is way overkill. You just need a thing that can read the `hhea` table and a thing that can read the `hmtx` table. However, I do need to point out that "half width" only means something in contexts where by default characters use the full quad, like CJK. Fonts that are simply designed for Latin blocks are proportional width, without any relation whatsoever to half the quad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need the source code '.hex' for the version of unifont you're using and the appropriate versions of the Unicode Utilities from [1]. 'unigenwidth' [2] seems to generate code related to the width of characters in Unifont; perhaps you'll need to write a parser to look through that code and give you what you want?

[1] http://unifoundry.com/unicode-utilities.html

[2] http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/unigenwidth.1.html